# awk compare columns from two files, impute values of another column

Tags: unix, awk

I want to compare the second columns from two files. If there is a match, print the corresponding value of the third column from the second file to the first file. If no match is found, fill with "NA"

```
File 1

1      rs1    AA    10
1      rs2    DD    20
1      rs3    EE    30
1      rs4    RR    40


File 2

1      rs1    Pascal
1      rs4    Albinoni


Desired output

1      rs1    AA    10    Pascal
1      rs2    DD    20    NA
1      rs3    EE    30    NA
1      rs4    RR    40    Albinoni
```

I have used this code, but it only output the matches:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1]=$2; next} $1 in a {print $0, a[$1]}' File2 File1
```

Thank you

Comment: http://theunixshell.blogspot.in/2012/12/i-have-two-files-file-1-contains-3.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$3;next}{print $0,a[$2]?a[$2]:"NA"}' file2 file1
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp1
1      rs1    AA    10
1      rs2    DD    20
1      rs3    EE    30
1      rs4    RR    40
> cat temp2
1      rs1    Pascal
1      rs4    Albinoni
> awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$3;next}{print $0,a[$2]?a[$2]:"NA"}' temp2 temp1
1      rs1    AA    10 Pascal
1      rs2    DD    20 NA
1      rs3    EE    30 NA
1      rs4    RR    40 Albinoni
>
```

Comment: How is determined that the correct index for the array a in this case is $2

Answer (score 3):

No exactly what you want, but using small tools is always nice. You can use [`join`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?join):

```
$ join -1 2 -2 2 -a1 file1 file2
rs1 1 AA 10 1 Pascal
rs2 1 DD 20
rs3 1 EE 30
rs4 1 RR 40 1 Albinoni
```

Explanation:

- `-1 2`: use second field of `file1` as join key
- `-2 2`: use seceond field of `file2` as join key
- `-a1`: left outer join on `file1`.

Comment: Join only works if sorted. Sorting can be slow for large files. However, do join -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.3 -e "NA" to achieve the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$3;next;}{print $0 "    " ($2 in a ? a[$2] : "NA")}' file2 file1
```

Output:

```
1      rs1    AA    10    Pascal
1      rs2    DD    20    NA
1      rs3    EE    30    NA
1      rs4    RR    40    Albinoni
```

Comment: Thank you. It works fine. Could you please explain what " " in the second action part does?

Comment: @user2162153 It appends a space. You could customize your separator with that.

Comment: Another way to put it is: `{printf "%s    %s\n", $0, ($2 in a ? a[$2] : "NA")}`

Comment: Thank you. Is it correct to say that the second condition i.e. `if $2 of the first file exists in array "a"` is written after `" "`?

Comment: After `"   "`, it appends `a[$2]` (which is `$3` of file2) if `$2` of file1 is a key in `a`, or "NA" if not.

Comment: Thank you. Just one more question, could you explain why this code would not work? `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$3;next;} $2 in a {print $0 "    " ($2 in a ? a[$2] : "NA")}' file2 file1`

Comment: @user2162153 It would only print those with a value from file2 obviously.