# awk to identify unique information in specific column in more than one file

Tags: awk, unique, match

I have a two part awk problem:

In the first part: I want to compare the second columns from two files. If there is a match, print the corresponding value in an output file.

In the second part: I also need the opposite information.  Again, I want to compare the second columns from the same two files. If there is a unique string value (meaning something that appears in Column 2 in file 1 and not in Column 2 in file 2).

To solve the first part: I have used the following awk

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1]=$2; next} $1 in a {print $0, a[$1]}' File2 File1
```

found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592736/awk-compare-columns-from-two-files-impute-values-of-another-column), which seems to solve the issue of identifying the matching values.

However, I cannot seem to find a solution to identifying the unique information from file 1 and printing it in a third output file. Can anyone provide any insight on how to solve this?

An example of the input is the following:

File 1

```
A   concept1    123
A   concept2    123
A   concept1    123
A   concept1    123
A   concept3    123
```

File 2

```
B   concept1    456
B   concept4    456
B   concept5    456
B   concept1    456
B   concept3    456
```

OUTPUT File 3

```
concept4
concept5
```

Thank you.

**UPDATE: In the original, I have asked the question comparing 1 file against one other file. Is it possible to modify this code to compare 1 file against multiple other files?**

For instance:

Input: FILE1 to be compared for any unique line against FILE2,FILE3,FILE4...FILEn OUTPUT: FILE with all unique lines from FILE1.

Comment: Could you provide some sample input and expected output?

Comment: Are you looking for `!($1 in a)` ?

Comment: glenn jackman: yes; Thor: check updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you are going about it in the wrong way. You are using `$1` as the index into the array, which is the same for every record.

**Small input files**

One approach to your problem is to save the second column into `a` and check it against the second file. Something like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[FNR]=$2; next} $2 != a[FNR] { print $2 }' File1 File2
```

Output:

```
concept4
concept5
```

**Large input files**

The above approach will use a lot of memory if the input files are very large. In that case a better way would be to preprocess the input like so:

```
paste <( <File1 tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2) \
      <( <File2 tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2) | 
  awk '$1 != $2 { print $2 }'
```

Output:

```
concept4
concept5
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your posted sample input files:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{seen[$2]++;next} seen[$2]{print $2}' file1 file2
concept1
concept1
concept3

$ awk 'NR==FNR{seen[$2]++;next} !seen[$2]{print $2}' file1 file2
concept4
concept5

$ awk 'NR==FNR{seen[$2]++;next} !seen[$2]{print $2}' file2 file1
concept2
```

Comment: Could this potentially work if include more than one file? Re: updated question. Meaning, the input (as is now) considers comparing the contents of Col2 in File1 against those in File 2 and the printing out those lines that appear in File 1 and not in File 2 in a third output File 3. Is is possible to add more filed to the input to achieve the same results, i.e. input File 1 (to be compared against) File2, File3, File4...FileN and output a File with those line that only appear in File 1 and not in any of the other N files?