# awk comparing two files and filling in blank rows with NA

Tags: unix, awk

I am trying to use a similar command from [awk compare columns from two files, impute values of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592736/awk-compare-columns-from-two-files-impute-values-of-another-column) , and looked a various questions that are similar to mine
[awk search column from one file, if match print columns from both files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31168521/awk-search-column-from-one-file-if-match-print-columns-from-both-files) ,
[How to import fields in other columns corresponding to one common field in two files with `NA` in all unmatched columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657850/how-to-import-fields-in-other-columns-corresponding-to-one-common-field-in-two-f) ,
[awk compare 2 files, 2 fields different order in the file, print or merge match and non match lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117346/awk-compare-2-files-2-fields-different-order-in-the-file-print-or-merge-match?rq=1)
with files that have more fields but I cannot get it to work. I also read from http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2012/12/i-have-two-files-file-1-contains-3.html to see if it would work but I am still having trouble:

File 1:

```
xx NC1 12 13 ! pro

xy NC1 15 17 ! pro

yx NC1 18 20 ! pro

yy NC1 22 28 ! pro
```

File 2

```
xx ds

xy jt

yy wp
```

desired output:

```
xx NC1 12 13 ! pro ds

xy NC1 15 17 ! pro jt

yx NC1 18 20 ! pro NA

yy NC1 22 28 ! pro wp
```

The code I am using:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1]=$6; next }{print $0 "   "  ($2 in a ? a[$2] : "NA")}' file2 file1
```

So basically my output gives me a new column that are all "NA" which obviously is not what I am trying to get to.

output:

```
xx NC1 12 13 ! pro NA

xy NC1 15 17 ! pro NA

yx NC1 18 20 ! pro NA

yy NC1 22 28 ! pro NA
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2;next}{print $0, ($1 in a ? a[$1]:"NA")}' f2 f1
```

Your problem is, you put the `file2` as the first argument, however, you *thought* it was `file1`. `file2` has no `$6` at all.

Comment: It worked, thank you. Do you mind providing me an explanation of what each part does so I can have a better understanding?

Comment: @JuDoe you wrote the original codes in your question, I suppose that you understand the stuff. which part do you have problem to understand

Comment: I wrote it barely understanding. This is what I understood and was able to find searching on the web. NR==FNR is used when you use two files. a[$1] is creating an array of the first field ? When it says a[$1]=$2 is it suggesting that the file has two columns? I read that next tells awk not to process any further commands and to read in the next record and start over. But honestly I do not understand what it is trying to do there. Does print $0 function a condition of when there is nothing to show that field?

Comment: @JuDoe `NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}` takes the first file (`file2`), build a hashtable (key=1st col, value=2nd col), when the file was finish processed, it's the turn of the 2nd file (`file1`), it will only be applied by `{print $0, ($1 in a ? a[$1]:"NA")}` check if col1 already in the hashtable( named `a`), then print, otherwise, print `NA`.